# Proguard and Android Adapters

Tags: android, proguard

I have heard that Android Activities should be kept. What about Adapters.  Like I have ArrayAdapter derived classes?  Is it required to keep these?  What about Views?

Comment: "I have heard that Android Activities should be kept". Kept what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generally keep the names of classes that are accessed using reflection. That includes anything listed in AndroidManifest.xml, as well as custom views, if they are referenced in `layout.xml` files. Adapters are usually set in code, so you shouldn't need to keep their names unobfuscated.

Comment: BTW Nikolay, I do you know why certain class names remain unobfuscated even though this is not specified in Prolog.cfg? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491625/how-to-tell-proguard-to-obfuscate-class-names

Comment: Not sure. Did you write the config file yourself, or are you using the one generated by Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

Currently you should add to `proguard-rules.pro`:

1) data classes for API-requests of REST libraries (Retrofit, Fuel, etc.),

2) WebView JavaScript interface,

3) some other classes that may change in `Release` build,

4) all, that offer libraries in their documentation.

See, for instance, https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/practical-proguard-rules-examples-5640a3907dc9.

Activities usually shouldn't be added (but I suppose, somebody can write data classes there, though it's a problem situation).

In my case I had to add several adapter's `ViewHolder` classes.