# How to obfuscate interface methods using proguard

Tags: android, proguard

How to obfuscate interface methods using proguard, I tried this but it doesn't work

```
-keep public interface * {
    !** <methods>;
}
```

Comment: How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: I decompiled the apk

Comment: So the decompiled apk contains the interface name and the method names unaltered? Is that what you are saying?

Comment: yes, I just want the method names obfuscated, not the interface

Comment: You're basically looking for an inverse of  `-keepclassmembernames`

`-keep` will keep everything, both the classname and the member names.

Comment: how about just `-obfuscatecode` with the listed method names?

Comment: i have a lot of methods that are private in various interfaces

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10491625/how-to-tell-proguard-to-obfuscate-class-names perhaps?

Comment: that didn't helped

Comment: add this `-printconfiguration "build/outputs/mapping/configuration.txt"` to your rules, look at what configuration it's actually using, and try to figure out why it came out the way it did :/

Comment: let me check it